# LINQ: Select single value from object array, by id

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, class, object

Take the following example class:

```
public class Questions
{
    public Int32 QuestionId { get; set; }
    public String Question { get; set; }
    public String Answer { get; set; }
}
```

And the following array:

```
var questionArray = new Questions[]
{
    new Questions {QuestionId = 1, Question = "How old are you?", Answer = "32"},
    new Questions {QuestionId = 2, Question = "What is your name?", Answer = "John"},
    new Questions {QuestionId = 3, Question = "How tall are you?", Answer = "6'"}
};
```

Using LINQ, I want to get the `Answer` for a specified `QuestionId`. For example, if I gave `QuestionId` 2, the result would be 'John'.

I want to be able to pull out the answer to a specific question to populate a separate DTO. ie:

```
var person = new PersonDto {Name = <single line LINQ goes here>};
```

So far I have only managed to get an answer using the following:

```
foreach (var q in questionArray.Where(q => q.QuestionId == 2))
{
    var answer = q.Answer;
}
```

Is this possible in 1 line of code?

Comment: yes it is possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Dom84 Updated the question with code I've tried.

Comment: so QuestionId is not unique in that case? what is your decision then to take one particular Element?

Comment: @Dom84 QuestionId is always unique. I've updated the question again with more info.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is possible using for e.g. `Single` from Linq, `Single` will throw exception when there will be more than one answer.

```
var answer = questionArray.Single(x=>x.QuestionId == 2).Answer;
```

This answer assumes that there is only one answer to one question (and it is always present). You can add `SingleOrDefault` and check for null if you are not sure if answer exists. Or you can add `Where` clause to get more than one answer, like:

```
var answers = questionArray.Where(x=>x.QuestionId == 2).Select(x=>x.Answer);
```

Above snippet will not fail if there is no answer to question and it will return empty sequence for it. You can test it for having a value and run `First` on it.

Comment: you could even add a .FirstOrDefault() at the back of your second code example. We can assume QuestionId to be unique within the questionArray

Comment: @Dbuggy not sure if we can assume that, that's why I suggested this approach.

Comment: I won't disagree with you there. However with OP needing 'I want to get the Answer for a specified QuestionId' is was safe imho there is one and only one answer available for a questionID. So i'm revising my previous comment and now state FirstOrDefault() should not be used at the end but SingleOrDefault :)

Comment: @wudzik Exactly what I needed! QuestionId is always unique and I know if it exists in questionArray or not, so your first line of code works perfectly.

Comment: @Dbuggy, also like your suggestion of adding .FirstOrDefault() to the end of the second code example. I tested this where QuestionId does not exist and works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

You are using the Wrong(tm) datatype. For lookups like these, use a Dictionary.

```
public class Question // Class names should be a singular form noun
{
    public int Id { get; set; } // QuestionId is redundant
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set; }
}

var questions = new Question[]
{
    new Questions {Id = 1, Question = "How old are you?", Answer = "32"},
    new Questions {Id = 2, Question = "What is your name?", Answer = "John"},
    new Questions {Id = 3, Question = "How tall are you?", Answer = "6'"}
}.ToDictionary(q => q.Id, q => q);

var answerToQuestionNumberTwo = questions[2].Answer;
```

EDIT: Clarification, the reason a dictionary is "better" here is because it is both more readable and is faster. You want to construct a collection meant for associating a question with a given ID, enabling you to do lookups on question objects to query their properties. This is the raison d'être of the Dictionary data structure and it has a lookup time complexity of O(1) (compared to O(n) of the Where/First/Single LINQ methods).